# Pass parrameter of custom enviroment as parameter of theorem

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm, framed

I want to create basically a shortcut for

```
\begin{sometheorem}[optional parameter]
    \leavevmode \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3pt} %some space adjustments
    \begin{leftbar}
        some text
    \end{leftbar}
\end{sometheorem}
```

so i tried:

```
\newenvironment{defi}[1]
{
\begin{definition}[#1]
\leavevmode \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3pt}
\begin{leftbar}\noindent
}
{
\end{leftbar}
\end{definition}
}
```

But this gives me

> **Theorem** (])
>
> Optional parameter] some text

What can i do, to properly pass the parameter along?

Edit: I am using the framed package for leftbar and amsthm for the theorems.

Comment: How or where is `leftbar` defined?

Comment: I am using leftbar from the framed package.

Comment: See tcolorbox instead. Tons of options including wrapping  already existing envs

Comment: How would I do this with tcolorbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to branch on whether the optional argument is given or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}

\newtheorem{innertheorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]
 {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \begin{innertheorem}%
  \else
    \begin{innertheorem}[#1]%
  \fi
  \mbox{}\par\nobreak
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3pt}%
  \begin{leftbar}\noindent\ignorespaces}
 {\end{leftbar}\end{innertheorem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some statement Some statement Some statement
Some statement Some statement Some statement
Some statement Some statement
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Something]
Some statement Some statement Some statement
Some statement Some statement Some statement
Some statement Some statement
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]